# Redirect a Django view

Tags: django, redirect, registration, reverse, profile

After a user logs into my app, I would like to redirect the person to their profile.
However, I keep getting this error:

> TypeError at /app/url/username/
>   profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

Here is the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank = True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

Here is the view where the user will log in and that will then redirect the user to the profile:

```
def user_login(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
           if user.is_active:
               login(request, user)

               url = reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': username})
            return redirect(url)

           else:
               return HttpResponse("Please login.")

         else:
             print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
             return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

     else:
         return render(request, 'reviews/login.html', {})
```

Here is the view for the user profile:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, user):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    return render(request, 'reviews/profile.html', {'username':username})
```

Here is the url pattern:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile')
```

Can someone tell me how to redirect the logged user to their profile?

Tried both approaches suggested so far. I received this error for both of them:

UserProfile matching query does not exist.

Here is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/app/profile/username/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'reviews',
 'compressor',
 'cloudinary')
 Installed Middleware:
 ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/var/www/nurse/lib/python3.4/site-   packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/nurse/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/nurse/nurseapp/reviews/views.py" in profile
165.      user=UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user)                       
File "/var/www/nurse/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method 127.                   return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/nurse/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get 334.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /app/profile/username/
Exception Value: UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible issues in your code:

First one, in `user_login` function when creating url for redirection using `reverse()`, you should pass `username` value in `args` instead of `kwargs`:

```
url = reverse('profile', args=(username,))
```

Second thing, it seems you named the parameter in profile url as `username` which means it will be passed into corresponding view function with the same name so you should rename `user` as `username` in view and update your logic as follows:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    p = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=username)
    return render(request, 'reviews/profile.html', 
        {'username': username, 'user': p.user, 'profile': p})
```

Please note that, for each `User` object, there must be one `UserProfile` corresponding to it. If you don't create a `UserProfile` object after new user signs up, you can try sending `User` object to your template instead:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'reviews/profile.html', 
        {'username': username, 'user': user})
```

It is a bad practice but, in `user_login` view, you can try creating `UserProfile` if not exists once user logs in:

```
def user_login(request):
    ...
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)   
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            ...
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, I tried your approach and got this error: UserProfile matching query does not exist.

Comment: @user2901792 Are you sure you create `UserProfile` object when a new user signs up? For each new `User`, a new `UserProfile` object should be created too.

Comment: I am bit of a newbie @ozgur. How do I create the UserProfile object when a new user signs up? Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Your veiw and regular expression do not match. Changed the user argument to username and I also changed your context to include the right variable. I also changed your redirect to an HttpResponseRedirect because it is much easier.You should not need to change anything else. But feel free to comment if you need more help.

```
from django.views.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect

def user_login(request):
   if request.method == 'POST': 
      username = request.POST.get('username')
      password = request.POST.get('password') 
      user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)   
        if user: 
            if user.is_active: 
              login(request, user)
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/{0}/').format(username)
            else:
               return HttpResponse("Please login.") 
      else: 
         print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)) 
         return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.") 
   else:
         return render(request, 'reviews/login.html', {})

@login_required
def profile(request, username):   
     user=User.objects.get(user = request.user)                       
     return render(request, 'reviews/profile.html', {'username':user})
```